# populating dropdowns depending on the other dropdown selected option from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am using codeigniter for a registration form, i need to make the dropdowns populate with countries,cities and states.I have already populated the country dropdown from mysql database but now i need to change the dropdown of city from the country selected and that too to be fetched from the database i.e. dynamically change of data...Please help
Country Database has : country_id Country_name
City Database has : City_id Fk_country_id City_Name.
Please help me with the code snippet for it coz am new to this...

Comment: Use ajax to accomplish this..onchaage  of country selectbox call ajax and append the output to state selectbox..same for populating city

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of country dropdown make one ajax request which will update state list javascript array or render full dropdown of state on completion of ajax request and similarly with city list.

Comment: can u help me with the code snippet as am new to this...Pls

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need your two drop down controls

```
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
  <option value="USA">United States</option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city">
</select>
```

then add the javascript to handle the selected value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name=country]').change(
    function(){
      $.post(); // post to a script that will return the data
    }
  );
});
```

then in your php code make other dorpdown options and then append that value intou your city.

Comment: My country name is taken from the database...i need to select the data from the database and on that select event need to change the value of the city which is again stored in the database...all should be dynamic

Comment: have you made a query that fetch country data from DB?